# How to make regex variables to capture of routes

Tags: php, regex, url, routes, sinatra

anyone can help me with this problem.

```
example $uri = '/username/carlos'; => $routes[] = '/username/@name';
```

@name convert in variable $name capturing string "carlos"

```
$routes[] = '/list/edit/@id:[0-9]{3}';

$routes[] = '/username/@name';

$routes[] = '/archive/*';

$routes[] = '/';


$uri = '/username/carlos';

foreach ( $routes as $pattern )
{
    if ( preg_match( '#^' . preg_replace( '#(?:{{)?@(\w+\b)(?:}})?#i', '(?P<\1>[\w\-\.!~\*\'"(),\s]+)',
                            str_replace( '\*', '(.*)', preg_quote( $pattern, '/' ) ) ) . '\/?$#i', $uri, $matchs ) )
    {

        //how to make regex for this to work :


        echo $name; // carlos =>$uri = '/username/carlos'; or matt => $uri = '/username/matt';

    }
}
```

thanks for reading

Comment: Why don't you use a readymade routing framework? And shouldn't you first break up the nested pattern conversion part to debug it?

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot more work you'd need to do to get this to work, primarily to convert the route's into regular expressions you can then use on the given URI. The way I would do it is as follows

```
$routes = $params = array();

$routes[] = '/list/edit/@id:[0-9]{3}';
$routes[] = '/username/@name';
$routes[] = '/archive/*';
$routes[] = '/';

$uri = '/username/carlos';

foreach($routes as $pattern) {
    // Convert all characters into safe characters
    $pattern = preg_quote($pattern, '~');

    // Convert * into .*?
    $pattern = preg_replace('/(?<!\\\\)\\\\\*/', '.*?', $pattern);

    #echo '<pre>'.print_r($pattern, true).'</pre>';
    // Convert any @name:expression into their expressions for capture
    $pattern = preg_replace_callback('%@([a-zA-Z]+)(\\\\:([^/]+))?%', 'regex_callback', $pattern);

    $pattern = '~^' . $pattern . '$~';

    if(preg_match($pattern, $uri, $matches)) {
        $params = $matches;
        break;
    }
}

echo '<pre>'.print_r($params, true).'</pre>';

function regex_callback($data) {
    #echo '<pre>'.print_r($data, true).'</pre>';
    $pattern = '[^/]+';
    if(!empty($data[3])) {
        $pattern = stripslashes($data[3]);
    }
    return '(?P<' . $data[1] . '>' . $pattern . ')';
}
```

It converts the `*` into `.*?`, and then converts the @param into `(?P<param>[^/]+)`, or substituting `[^/]+` for the expression after the `:`

If a match is found, it sets the matches to `$params`, and exits the foreach loop. To find the name, you would then just need to use

```
echo $param['name'];
```

Comment: Hi, how to regex for $uri = '/list/edit/123.html'; with $routes[] = '/list/edit/@id:[0-9]{3}.html'; result is "123.html" but no work single var "123" sorry my english!

Comment: You could just use basename instead to retrieve that. http://www.php.net/basename